# PDFbox Document Propperties will not set

Tags: metadata, document, pdfbox

In Tutorialspoint is learn about PDFbox.
[PDFbox Tutorialpoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pdfbox/pdfbox_document_properties.htm)
I put an method in my programm to update the metadata from an existing PDF-File.
The Document Properties will not set and i spent many hours to find out why.
When the modification date ".setModificationDate()" will be wrong or coment out, the meatadata of documet properties will not changed.
I dont want to put a static date as the tutorial, i want to insert variables.

```
//Setting the created date of the document 
Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
date.set(2015, 11, 5);

//Setting the modified date of the document 
date.set(2016, 6, 5);

// Save the metadata to file
pdfDocument.setModificationDate(date);
```

The data of the  ".setModificationDate()" method are want a "Calendar" type.
I do it on different ways and nothing will be work.
Try first

```
Calendar transfomedDate = new GregorianCalendar();
transfomedDate = convertStringDateToCalendar(StringDate);

Calendar modifiedDate = new GregorianCalendar();
modifiedDate.set(transfomedDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),

transfomedDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),
transfomedDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
transfomedDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
transfomedDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
transfomedDate.get(Calendar.SECOND));

pdfDocument.setModificationDate(modifiedDate);
```

This Methos will be work correctly on creating Date but not on mofdificationDate?
Then i will trying to put the parameters of the modification in "int" variables and use it on this way.

```
Calendar transfomedDate = new GregorianCalendar();
transfomedDate = convertStringDateToCalendar(StringDate);

int year = transfomedDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = transfomedDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = transfomedDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

Calendar modifiedDate = new GregorianCalendar();
// modifiedDate.set(2017, 10, 11);
modifiedDate.set(year, month, day);

pdfDocument.setModificationDate(modifiedDate);
```

It will not work to.
I dont knwo why PDFbox will not aipdate the metadate when the modficationDate will be commet out or be wrong. I can be ignore the it are wrong?
I dont know what i can do now?
Thanks
Mike

Comment: Please improve your question to create some working code that does something, tell what it outputs then describe what you expected. I doubt that `pdfDocument.setModificationDate(modifiedDate);` would work if `pdfDocument` is a `PDDocument`: the method doesn't exist for it.

Comment: I coded some example to show what for a problem i have. The example code will be work but in my Programm it dont want to work. The Problem will come when i want to create an modifyDate. Then all Metadatas will not Saved. I cant show a code that will be work. When i want to extract the methods and make it runing out of the other code then it will be work too? I´m very depressed.

Comment: pdfDocument ist an PDDDocument it will be created by PDDocument pdfDocument = new PDDocument.

Comment: PDDocument does not have a `setModificationDate` method. At least not in 2.0.7. And where does this `convertStringDateToCalendar` come from???

Comment: please include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve